# How do I gather connection statistics in Jetty 9

Tags: java, jetty

I want to migrate my app from jetty 7 to 9.
In Jetty 7 I iterated through server connectors and got all information

```
for (int i = 0; i < server.getConnectors().length; i++) {
    long durationMax = server.getConnectors()[i].getConnectionsDurationMax();
    long openMax = server.getConnectors()[i].getConnectionsOpenMax();
    long requestsMax = server.getConnectors()[i].getConnectionsRequestsMax();
}
```

How do I do it in Jetty 9 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectorStatistics](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.0.6.v20130930/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ConnectorStatistics.html)

```java
// Add the statistics module to the connector
ConnectorStatistics stats = new ConnectorStatistics();
connector.addBean(stats);

// Then access the information.
System.out.printf("Connector.getConnections() = %,d%n", stats.getConnections());
System.out.printf("Connector.getConnectionsOpen() = %,d%n", stats.getConnectionsOpen());
System.out.printf("Connector.getConnectionsMax() = %,d%n", stats.getConnectionsMax());
```

See the [Javadoc](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.0.6.v20130930/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ConnectorStatistics.html) for the other values that are collected and available via getters.

Stats are also available via JMX if you enable JMX.

Comment: The `ConnectorStatistics` module has been deprecated in 9.3.14+. Use `ServerConnectionStatistics.addToAllConnectors(server);`